# How do I change the default directory of Anaconda?

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda

I like to learn python. Thus, I installed Anaconda on my MacBook (Mac OS X High Sierra). After my first stumbling steps with JupyterLab I recognized that all notebooks and txt files are saved in my home directory. However, I like to keep the folder nice and clean. How do I change the default folder directory?

Therefore, I have generated the Jupyter config file with

```
 jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and then I changed the notebook directory line to:

```
 c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/Users/name/folder/Python_scripts/'
```

After restarting Jupyter, I was expecting that new files were deposited in the new folder, but nothing changed. New files are still saved in the home directory.

Comment: what do you mean by new files?

Comment: New notebook or text files that I save within JupiterLab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter notebook by default will use whatever the current working directory is of the terminal session. To do what you are looking for in the terminal with jupyter:

```sh
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=<some_directory>
```

This will set the kernel to be in `<some_directory>`
Normally you would want to launch jupyter from the directory you want to be in:

```sh
cd <directory_you_want>
jupyter notebook
```

To move your files (I'm assuming you want to move all of your notebooks):

```sh
cd ~ && find *.ipynb print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} <directory_you_want>
```

Comment: Thank you C.Nivs. This helped a lot. Just to be very specific. The mistake I've done was that I used the Anaconda Navigator to start a JupyterLab session. The Navigator does not allow to pass further options to the terminal command in the backend (at least I do not see how). So, from now on I will start my sessions in the correct folder with the command `jupyter lab --notebook-dir=<some_directory>`.